# forever-monitor send email on crash

Tags: node.js, crash, restart, forever, forever-monitor

I want to use forever-monitor package to send me an email when my server crashes.

By going to the homepage I can see that an error is created and my server is restarted after the error. But I want to be able to capture these events (restart and error) so that I can log and send warning emails. But my debugger doesn't stop on error and restart events. Also, those console messages aren't printed.

I run it from command line as node myfilename.js, app.js is my main file.

Thanks for the help !

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: false,
    args: [],
});

child.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('An error occured '+err);
});

child.on('restart', function() {
    console.log('Restarting file');
});

child.start();

setTimeout(function () {
      throw new Error('I created an error');
}, 200);
```

Comment: Did you do anything about it?

Comment: I was killing the process by cmd+c from terminal but that was also killing the forever process, according to another question I found here. My methodology was wrong. Since forever was killed as well, it wasnt able to send an email to me on crash, as expected.

Comment: Bear with me, but doesn't forever-monitor exit after you deploy? When I run node forever-monitor-file.js it just exits the process and nothing happens. What could be happening?